# c# asp.net use Windows Forms WebBrowser

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have a class of library code which uses a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control to load a web page then extract information from the DOM tree, etc... I've found this to be the only reliable way to be able to parse information loaded onto a page with javascript, etc...

This worked fine when testing with console app, but when I call the same method from an asp.net page (ASP.NET MVC Controller) it crashes with a "ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment."... i've tried adding [STAThread] to my method but that doesn't seem to help!

Any ideas?

Thanks

Update:

I need to allow a page to complete load and execute all its javascript, then search it for text that matches a template I have already stored... Don't think HtmlAgilityPack will work?  Does WatIn run the javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save yourself a lot of headache and use [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net) instead of a WebBrowser control.

See this question: [Best method for Website Automation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549538/best-method-for-website-automation/1592325#1592325)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is impossible to get IIS to run in single thread apartment model (STA).  Instead of using the WebBrowser control, you could take a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).  It will let your read in a web page and poke around the DOM.  The WebBrowser control uses lots of computer resources that you won't have to worry about it make the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the `System.Windows` is intended for desktop, not web stuff. I agree with Jake Pearson that you should use something else. But if you want you can try forcing the page into STA mode using this directive:

```
<%@Page AspCompat="true"%>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk9h2kb.aspx