# extract text content from web page using asp.net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i'm trying the load a page to may asp.net web form and extract only the text from it and display the extracted text in an `Areatext`

like this:
[image]

and my code is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #form1 {
            height: 500px;
            width: 1199px;
        }
        .auto-style1 {}
        #TextArea1 {
            height: 288px;
            width: 1157px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Text="Clike me" 
                    OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"        
                    Width="160px" CssClass="auto-style1" Height="32px" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>CNN</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>BBC</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>FOX</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <textarea id="TextArea1" name="S1" runat="server" ></textarea></form>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Uri url = null;
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(DisplayText);

        if (RadioButtonList1.Text == "CNN")
        {
            url = new Uri("http://www.edition.cnn.com/");
            wb.Url = url;
            //Response.Redirect(url);
        }
        else if (RadioButtonList1.Text == "BBC")
        {
            url = new Uri("http://www.bbc.com/");
            wb.Url = url;
        }
        else
        {
            url = new Uri("http://www.foxnews.com/");
          wb.Url = url;
        }

    }

    private void DisplayText(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;

        wb.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);

        wb.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);

        TextArea1.Value = Clipboard.GetText();

    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

but i have this error in line

```
 WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
```

ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.

so what i'm doing wrong pleas help and many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have never attempted to use WebBrowser in an object-reference, but I know that this being a web-Form means you will be receiving post backs, and if you re-instantiate the Browser reference each time, it isn't going to operate like the Page object.  I would just use the Page object, you can collect any controls and methods needed, while also utilizing Request/Response namespaces.  I would also match on the radiobuttonlist control like the code below:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack) 
        {
             string url;
             RadioButtonList rdl = new RadioButtonList();
             url = rdl.SelectedItem.Text; 
        }  
    }
```

Of course you'd just grab the `.SelectedItem.Text` from your markup-based RadioButtonList, instead of building one.

I checked, and it also seems like the `WebBrowser` object is under `System.Windows.Forms`.  From my experience, you never want to use that Library in Web Forms (bad experiences with `MsgBox`).

I'd refactor using the sample above and just

```
Response.Redirect(url);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using an approach based upon a different automation control such as  WatiN (c.f. [c# asp.net use Windows Forms WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071930/c-sharp-asp-net-use-windows-forms-webbrowser)) or something like the HTML Agility Pack (c.f. [Best method for Website Automation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549538/best-method-for-website-automation/))

Answer (score 0):

You can use [html agility pack](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691119/Html-Agility-Pack-Massive-information-extraction-f). Here is a sample code, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4182886/145682):

```
var root = doc.DocumentNode;
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var node in root.DescendantNodesAndSelf())
{
    if (!node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        string text = node.InnerText;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            sb.AppendLine(text.Trim());
    }
}
```

An example code to show how to download the web page, you can try the following code (taken from [here](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples)):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");
```